# Searching for partial matches in a list using another list in Powershell

Tags: powershell

The "-contains" operator in Powershell requires an exact match (no wildcards). The "-match" operator allows for wildcards and partial matches. If I want to perform a partial/wildcard match for a list of possible matches, how should I do this?

For example:

```
$my_match_list = @("Going","Coming","Leaving","Entering")
$my_strings_list = @("Going home", "Coming over", "Leaving the house", "Entering a competition")
```

"Going" will -match "Going home", but $my_strings_list will not -contains "Going"
For now I worked around this by looping through, but it doesn't look like it should be the best way:

```
foreach($i in $my_strings_list){
  foreach($y in $my_match_list){
   if($i -match $y){
    do.something
   }
  }
}
```

How should I approach this?
For the specific task I'm actually querying a large AD db for all users matching 1 of several descriptions. I want it to look as neat as possible. I had something like:

```
$myVar = get-aduser -filter {blah -ne blah} -properties description | ?{$_.description -match "blah1" -or (etcetcetc)
```

But it became a horribly long list of possible matches in the filter string. So then I grabbed everything into a variable and processed out the actual matches I wanted. But it still looks like I should be able to do the task in fewer lines. Perhaps just 1 long regex string and put that into the filter?

```
|?{$_.description -match "something|something|something|something"
```

?

EDIT: Regex might be the shortest I guess:

```
$my_match_list = "going|coming|leaving|entering"
foreach($i in $my_strings_list){if($i -match $my_match_list){do.something}}
```

So:

```
get-aduser -filter {blah -ne blah} -properties description | ?{$_.description -match $my_match_list}
```

I would have preferred something more like "get-blah blah | ?{$_.description in $my_match_list} because its easier to add things to a list than to add them to a regex.

Comment: So then add them to a list, and convert to a regex. `$filter = "($($ArrayOfStuff -join "|"))"` turns `@("Bob","June","Michael")` into `"(Bob|June|Michael)"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$my_match_list = @("Going","Coming","Leaving","Entering")
$my_strings_list = @("Going home", "Coming over", "Leaving the house", "Entering a competition")

[regex]$Match_regex = ‘(‘ + (($my_match_list |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)’

$my_strings_list -match $Match_regex

Going home
Coming over
Leaving the house
Entering a competition
```

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex.aspx